# Translating JSON object into HashMap with serde_json

Tags: rust, serde

I'm trying to parse a JSON object into a HashMap in Rust using `serde_json`. With the following code, I get the error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of index of `Value`
```

How do I get that `Value` into my HashMap?

```
use serde_json::{Result, Value};
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {

  let variables_json = r#"{
    "awayTeamAbbrev": "DAL",
    "homeTeamAbbrev": "TB",
    "gameInstanceUid": "cbs-nfl-pickem-challenge",
    "sportType": "NFL",
    "weekNumber": 1
  }"#;
  let keys = vec!["sportType","weekNumber"];
  dbg!(json_to_hashmap(&variables_json, keys));
    
}  

fn json_to_hashmap(json: &str, keys: Vec<&str>) -> Result<HashMap<String, Value>> {
    let lookup: Value = serde_json::from_str(json).unwrap();
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    for key in keys {
        let varname = key.to_owned();
        let value = lookup[&varname];
        map.insert(varname, value);
    }
    Ok(map)

}
```

Comment: You can make a clone of the value with `let value = lookup[&varname].clone();` to avoid the move.

Comment: @Joe_Jingyu That worked, thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get a `HashMap<String, Value>` directly from `serde_json::from_str`, then use `remove_entry` to take the values out without cloning:

```
fn json_to_hashmap(json: &str, keys: Vec<&str>) -> Result<HashMap<String, Value>> {
    let mut lookup: HashMap<String, Value> = serde_json::from_str(json).unwrap();
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    for key in keys {
        let (k, v) = lookup.remove_entry (key).unwrap();
        map.insert(k, v);
    }
    Ok(map)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d26b586a27c73dd2d11e3669d9bb203c)